# windows batch parentheses scope

Tags: windows, batch-file, scope, parentheses

How can I set result variable in a scope surrounded with parantheses ('if' or 'for'-loop). The result is correct (>> RESULT: aaa = bbb), when procedure is called directly, and fails when used in for-loop or if-statement (>> RESULT: ccc = ).

```
:: =====================================
@setlocal
@echo off
@rem (1)
call :testReturn aaa
echo RESULT: aaa = %aaa%

@rem (2)
if "1" == "1" (
call :testReturn ccc
echo RESULT: ccc = %ccc%
)

goto :eof

:testReturn
set %~1=bbb
exit /b
endlocal
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

When a compound statement enclosed in parentheses is to be executed,
the statement is first parsed from the open parenthesis all of the
way to the matching close-parenthesis.

At this time, any `%var%` is replaced by that `var`'s value from the 
environment **AT THE TIME IT IS PARSED** (ie its **PARSE-TIME** value.)

**THEN** if the statement seems valid, it is executed.

There are three common ways of accessing the **RUN-TIME** value of the
variable (as a `FOR` loop executes, for instance.)

1/ `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` which switches to a mode where
!var! may be used to access the runtime value of `var`
2/ `CALL set var2=%%var%%` to set the value of `var2` from the 
runtime value of `var`
3/ Executing a subroutine, internal or external within which `%var%` 
will be the runtime value.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
ECHO START of run %%i
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time! - PARSE TIME was %time%
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
timeout /t 5
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time!
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
ECHO END of run %%i
ECHO.
)
GOTO :eof

:report
ECHO :report says TIME is %TIME%
GOTO :eof
```

A few items to note:

1. The instruction

   IF ERRORLEVEL n echo errorlevel is n OR GREATER

   ***ALWAYS*** interprets the RUN-TIME value of `ERRORLEVEL`
2. `IF SET VAR` ***ALWAYS*** interprets the RUN-TIME value of `VAR`
3. The `magic variables` like ERRORLEVEL and TIME should never
   be SET. If you execute

   SET ERRORLEVEL=dumb

then `ERRORLEVEL` will adopt the value `dumb` because the current
value in the environment takes priority over the system-assigned value.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation! It helps me certainly in my future scripts. And the current problem is solved too - needed some work for files of required length.

Answer (score 1):

inside a code block (=surrounded with parantheses) you need `delayed expansion` and `!variables!`, **not** `%variables%`:

```
:: =====================================
@setlocal
@echo off
@rem (1)
call :testReturn aaa
echo RESULT: aaa = %aaa%

@rem (2)
if "1" == "1" (
call :testReturn ccc
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo RESULT: ccc = !ccc!
endlocal
)

goto :eof

:testReturn
set %~1=bbb
exit /b
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you, Endoro! Simple but very helpful. Problem solved - find file of some length:
`code`
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.png') do (
 call :strlen result %%f
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 if /i "!result!" == "6" ...SOME_WORK...
 endlocal
)
goto :eof
:strlen <string_length> <string>
setlocal
set string=%~2 
set string=%string:"=%^

&for /f "delims=: " %%a in (
'set string^|findstr/o $') do (
set /a str_len=%%a-9)
(endlocal&set "%~1=%str_len%"
exit/b)
`code`

Comment: @meine -- can't read your code in the comment here. Put it at pastebin or (better) make a new question.

Comment: it is not a new question, but a part of total script only, where your answer helped me. :)